# How to reference to a global variable in a fragment from a class ANDROID

Tags: android, reference, global-variables, fragment

I have made a custom dialog interface(defined into a separate fragment) that is called from a fragment if necessary. This dialog interface inflate a listView and so i called a custom list adapter (extended BaseAdapter). Now i want to refer to a global variable defined into the dialog fragment from the custom list adapter. How can i do it?

**EDIT**

I want to achieve a dialog fragment with this custom layout:

```
      ****DIALOG TITLE****
ListView where each row have this layout:
    ICON - SOME TEXT - SwitchWidget
```

I have this fragment:

```
public class FilterDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

//Checked is a class that store some info
public ArrayList<Checked> mSelectedItem; <--- variable i want to modify

public static FilterDialogFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Checked> checked) {
    FilterDialogFragment fragment = new FilterDialogFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();


    args.putParcelableArrayList("ARRAYLIST_STRING", checked);

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mSelectedItem = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("ARRAYLIST_STRING");

    String[] checkItem = new String[mSelectedItem.size()];
    boolean[] isChecked = new boolean[mSelectedItem.size()];


    for(int i=0; i<mSelectedItem.size(); i++) {
        checkItem[i]=""+mSelectedItem.get(i).getWhatChecked();
        if(mSelectedItem.get(i).getShow()==1) {
            //show
            isChecked[i]=true;
        } else {
            isChecked[i]=false;
        }
    }

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    Button ok_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);

    ok_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, getActivity().getIntent());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    CustomListAdapterDialog mAdapter = new CustomListAdapterDialog(getActivity());
    mAdapter.addItem(new DialogModel(R.color.green, checkItem[i], isChecked[i]));

    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    dialog.setContentView(view);

    return dialog;
}
```

And this is my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapterDialog extends BaseAdapter {
    [....]
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    //System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);


    if(convertView == null) {
        //initialize the view Holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_row_layout, null);

                viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.marker);
                viewHolder.tvNomeChecked = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_marker);
                viewHolder.swCheck = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checked_item);


                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_section_layout, null);

                viewHolder.tvSeparator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_alert_dialog);
                break;

        }

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final DialogModel model;
    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            model =(DialogModel) mData.get(position);

            //viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(model.getMarkerIcon());
            viewHolder.ivIcon.setBackgroundResource(model.getMarkerColor());
            viewHolder.tvNomeChecked.setText(model.getNomePercorso());
            if(model.isCkeck()) {

                viewHolder.swCheck.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                viewHolder.swCheck.setChecked(false);

            }

            viewHolder.swCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                     //HERE I WANT TO CALL THE mSelectedItem OF MY FilterDialogFragment
                }
            });
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            model =(DialogModel) mData.get(position);

            viewHolder.tvSeparator.setText(model.getNomeSection()   );
            break;

    }
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvNomeChecked;
    TextView tvSeparator;
    Switch swCheck;
}
```

Comment: create instance of dialog fragment, then you can access its public variable using its instance anywhere in app

Comment: I already create an instance of the dialog fragment. I need to reference to that instance and not a new one because i do some operations on the global variable

Answer (score 0):

If there is any direct/indirect relation between dialog and fragment?
If yes then use interface to pass your variable, if not than you can use static variable, but try to avoid static variable/classes and change your code to avoid static keyword
Create interface and implement it in your dialog fragment than pass this reference to your adapter and initialize it in your adapter, and use it

Comment: the dialog is a fragment. i want to refer to the variable defined into the dialog fragment from the adapter class

Comment: Share some code, I couldn't understand what you want to achieve and most importantly why?